# dynamic pages with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dynamic-pages

I currently have dynamic pages. For example, `index.php?p=proposal` opens a page from `/pages/landing.php` in the root of my website `www/researchportal/`

Currently, the page `http://localhost/researchportal/proposal` does seem to load by its own (just the content of proposal.php, no CSS), but not through the index.php file. Which means that the CSS is not loaded properly.

```
http://localhost/researchportal/index.php?p=proposal
```

This link loads up properly with the CSS loaded.

```
http://localhost/researchportal/proposal
```

This link doesn't contain the header and CSS which are defined in the index.php file.

My .htaccess file located in the root of my website `www/researchportal/`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$ index.php?p=$1
```

Why isnt `http://localhost/researchportal/proposal` loading properly?

Answer (score 0):

I think the server request for xxx.css is rerouted to index.php you should add an exeption for your css and image directory to your regex pattern. Allowing an exception for robots.txt would be usefull too.

Answer (score 0):

Your current rule will send all requests to index.php. You need to add a condition to prevent requests for actual files/directories that exist e.g. css from being sent to index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
#Also recommend that you add a an explicit RewriteBase
RewriteBase /

#only run this rule if the request is not for an existing file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$ index.php?p=$1
```